# What is the initial class in a new Flash Builder project supposed to represent?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm learning Flash Builder so I can add some extra functionality to my Flash Pro project.

Let's say I create a new Flash Pro file called foo.fla.  I can then open Flash Builder and create a new project (and in the setup wizard I specify my foo.fla file as the target of the project).  The wizard then creates a new project containing one file called foo.as which extends Sprite.

Now I would expect this initial file to be a root of some kind, and a great central place where I could create variables that all my MovieClips need to share.  However, I can't figure out what exactly this file is being used for when my project is run.  It doesn't seem to correspond to the stage or to the parent of any of my movie clips.  It's constructor doesn't even seem to be called.  What is this file used for?  Is there a way I can use it to store 'global' stuff?

Comment: It is "root" or in Flash parlance - the "Document Class" see: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash--active-3233

Answer (score 0):

In order to "link" it to your FLA, you'll want to set it as the document class:

[image: document properties]

Once you do that, the constructor should be called at startup.

Answer (score 0):

This class is exactly what you think it is: root*.

The class that you provide is the class that is associated with your .fla file.
It is called the document class or main class.

You are probably familiar with the concept of associating a library symbol with a class.
Say you create a MovieClip, add it to your library and define a class for it.

This is pretty much the same thing now, except you add the class to the document.

When the flash player executes your .swf file, it will instantiate your class and add it to the display list. This has a couple of implications:
The class must be some DisplayObject, because it is added to a DisplayObjectContainer.
This is why you it extends Sprite. (Sprite is a lightweight class that you should prefer over MovieClip if you do not need a timeline)

This is the strange part, remember * up there?
Yes, as your swf is created, the document class is instantiated and the resulting object is added to the display list, this means that root isn't actually the root of the display hierarchy. There's a parent container and that is stage.
Think of root as the root of your application, not necessarily the top most root of all roots.

And here's the (imo) strangest thing:
You can access the stage property within the constructor of the document class.
This is not true for any other class that extends DisplayObject (unless you force it by passing stage as a parameter to the constructor, which you shouldn't be doing)) and who's objects will end up on the display list, because you have to addChild them after they are created.
You might be tempted to use the stage property in such a constructor that is a constructor of a document class (because you can), but this leads to problems, because you can never tell if your document class is actually used as a document class.
If you want to instantiate your current document class in some other project, it will not have the special status of being the document class. It will be some regular class as all the others of that project.
In this case, stage will be null in the constructor. So don't access stage in the constructor, even if you can.
If you need stage, wait for it to be available. That is when the ADDED_TO_STAGE Event fires.